# how to write to a samba folder using vbs?

Tags: vbscript, samba, smb

Can someone show me an example how to create a directory and file on a samba share using VBscript?

I tried to search on google, but i didn't found something helpful.

this is my piece of code

```
ServerShare = "\\10.10.10.10\share"
UserName = "user-pc\login"
Password = "passwd"

Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password
```

but i don't know what is the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the share to an actual drive letter, then use [`CreateFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kby5ae3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to create a new folder on that drive:

```
...
NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "X:", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password

FSO.CreateFolder "X:\new_folder"

NetworkObject.RemoveNetworkDrive "X:"
```